# How can I set layout height and width programmatically which support all screen size in Android?

Tags: android

I want to set textview height and width programmatically which support all screen sizes.

Here is my activity.xml in which I have two LinearLayout. In the second layout I put multiple textview dynamically more than 10 or 12.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    tools:context="com.example.sagargajera.setballs.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6">
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_balls"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#3F51B5"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <!--Here I tried to put layout and inside this layout I want to put textview. -->
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity.java in which i tried to create layout and textview according to my loop.

```
package com.example.sagargajera.setballs;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout layout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        layout=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.layout_balls);

//        DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
//        int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels;
//        int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;

        for(int i=1;i<=12;i++){
//            LinearLayout.LayoutParams param1=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width, (height/7));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams param1=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
            LinearLayout layout_1=new LinearLayout(this);
            layout_1.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            layout_1.setLayoutParams(param1);
            layout_1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            layout_1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f32f32"));

            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20,20);
            param1.weight=1;
            TextView tv=new TextView(this);
            tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            tv.setLayoutParams(params);
            tv.setText("" + i);
            tv.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cicle));
            tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));

            layout_1.addView(tv);
            layout.addView(layout_1);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my screenshot:

[image]

Above code which create layout as well as textview. A Textview is set inside the dynamic layout and dynamic layout is set inside my xml specific layout namely layout_balls.

The problem is when I run this app in small device it give me perfect output but when I run this app in large devices or tablet output was unexpected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the device density like this:

```
float scaledDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20 * scaledDensity,20 * scaledDensity);
        param1.weight=1;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some little bit change on below post.

```
float scaledDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20 * scaledDensity,20 * scaledDensity);
        param1.weight=1;
```

The only change is we need to convert float into int so use below:

```
float scaledDensity = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams params=new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(20 * (int)scaledDensity,20 * (int)scaledDensity);
            param1.weight=1;//This is the correct answer.
```